# how to write a count of particular column greater than one in spark sql using scala API

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT SECTOR, COUNT(REGION) FROM SAMPLE_TABLE GROUP BY SECTOR HAVING COUNT(REGION) > 1
```

I want convert it into Spark using Spark SQL's DataFrame API. How can I do this?

Comment: what have you tried ? provide an example and some errors or some concrete question of your understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can work:

```scala
val df = sqlContext.table("SAMPLE_TABLE")
val newDF = df
  .groupBy("sector")
  .agg(count("region").as("cnt"))
  .where($"cnt" > 1)
```

For more information, you can take a look at the [DataFrame API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) and the [`functions` package documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$)

Comment: @praveen Please consider marking the answer as correct if it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
    sqlContext.sql("SELECT SECTOR, COUNT(REGION) FROM SAMPLE_TABLE GROUP BY SECTOR HAVING COUNT(REGION) > 1
").take(1000).foreach(println)
```

what do you mean by using API? which one?